# Share redux state among workspaces or libraries inside a monorepo

Tags: reactjs, redux, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I’m recently having a hard time to understand how to manage some logic between shared apps and libs, in particular with `redux` setted up in the main app and the need to use it on the shared-ui components.

On a nutshell:

I have a **react-app** and a **shared UI library** on an **NX monorepo** (but it's package-based so it's basically an *npm monorepo*):

```
Nx-project/
├── apps/
│   └── react-app/
│       └── redux-store.js
└── libs/
    └── shared-ui/
        └── component-that-use-redux
```

I need to use redux hooks (from react-app) inside my shared UI component.
How should I proceed, what's the best practice here?

Should I simply import from the app?
Doesn’t that represent a conflictual issue when it comes to compile the shared ui lib?

Thanks in advance for any insight you can give me.

Comment: You could argue that a UI library should be state management agnostic and simply expect any data the components need as props. The connect API is perfect for that. You'd have thin wrapper components in your react-app that wire up the state and the UI component functions purely on props. For example `<ConnectedFancyButton>` in react-app and `<FancyButton>` in shared-ui. This however is a lot of work if your components need to be migrated from react-app to shared-ui and they use a lot of `useSelector` etc. Then Stuart Nichols answer is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't import from the app to the lib. Create another NX library for your actions, reducers, types, etc, and import them into your app as well. You can use the Redux package hooks in your UI library (i.e. import from redux). I don't know exactly what the flavour of Redux is that you are using, but basically you can use the official Redux hooks, and reducers, actions and types from your separate NX library inside your app. Try to put as little code as possible in your app and keep your NX libraries small and everything should fit in to place.

Comment: If this isn't clear, let me know and I will try and explain further.

Comment: mm so you are saying that all the redux state should be on a separate library, but should it contain only the slices? Where should I define the store.ts? Inside the react-app or inside the redux library? I'm using RTK Toolkit so I have slices that contains actions, hooks, etc... also with RTK Query (and it's hooks).

Comment: The store should be defined inside the app, but should only be boilerplate. All custom code should live inside libraries. The way I have done it is to have a folder in the libs folder called /apps. Then in that folder I have a folder for every app in my mono-repo. Inside that folder is a collection of separate libraries that are specifically for that app. If a UI component is dependant on logic that is app specific, it isn't really sharable across multiple applications and therefore lives in the app specific library folder.

Comment: Similarly, if a store slice is sharable across multiple applications then it could live inside the shared library folder and not in the lib/apps folder.

Comment: The RTK Toolkit functions can be imported into libraries as well as apps.

Comment: ok it makes sense indeed. I find also this guide that apply a similar aproach, you mean like this right? https://blog.nrwl.io/step-by-step-guide-on-creating-a-monorepo-for-react-native-apps-using-nx-704753b6c70e#bb4f  
I was wondering if it makes sense to have the rtk query service and the rtk redux hooks in the same shared library though.

Comment: A general rule is that if logic is coupled, keep it in the same library. I tend name the NX library so as to indicate what it does without looking at the code inside. If there is an "and" in the name, it should probably live inside 2 libraries.